# Text file generation from table using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table named `Account`

I created OLE DB Source and Flat File destination in DFT

[image]

If I create Account.txt in C:\data path manually,I have to show it in File Name Tab.

Is there any way to create the text file automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Complete the SSIS package and deploy it to a SQL Server
Then when you try to execute it on SQL Server, you will be able to create the script of the task

For example, following is from my sample SSIS export package

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'Kodyaz', @project_name=N'ExportSQL2TextFile', @use32bitruntime=False, @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  @object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

You can customize the destination file properties here in this script